# I am writing my first 80x86 Assembly Language graphical interface application, and I am having trouble accepting a user input

Tags: assembly, x86

I am fairly new to 80x86 Assembly Language programming and I need help with an interesting problem. The main purpose of the project I am working on is to familiarize myself with the process of coding simple graphical interfaces. The code that I currently have is fairly simple, I am using the MessageBoxA external procedure to produce a Message Box like this:
[Simple Message Box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnzvW.png)

The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
; msgbox
; This program displays a small "message box" window.
; Assemble with: ml /c /coff msgbox.asm
; Link with: link /subsystem:console msgbox kernel32.lib user32.lib

.386
.model flat, stdcall
public _start

ExitProcess proto near32 stdcall, dwExitCode:dword

GetStdHandle proto near32 stdcall, nStdHandle:dword

ReadFile proto near32 stdcall, hFile:dword, lpBuffer:near32,            

NumberOfCharsToRead:dword, lpNumberOfBytesRead:near32, lpOverlapped:near32

MessageBoxA proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword

std_input       equ     -10
std_output      equ     -11

.stack  4096

.data

input           byte    ?
input2          byte    ?
read            dword   ?
read2           dword   ?
written         dword   ?
hStdIn          dword   ?
test2           byte    "stranger"     ; used this for second output in place of 'input2' to produce the picture seen above.
MsgBoxCaption   byte    100 DUP (?)
MsgBoxText      byte    100 DUP (?)

.code

_start:
        ; accept 5 character user input, and stores it in 'input.'
        invoke  GetStdHandle, std_input
        mov     hStdIn, eax
        invoke  ReadFile, hStdIn, near32 PTR input, 5, near32 PTR read, 0

        mov     ecx,5                      ; loops through 5 characters
        mov     ebx,0
move:   mov     al,input[ebx]
        mov     MsgBoxCaption[ebx],al
        inc     ebx
        loop    move

        ; accept 2nd input. This time 8 characters --- Doesn't work
        invoke  GetStdHandle, std_input
        mov     hStdIn, eax
        invoke  ReadFile, hStdIn, near32 PTR input2, 8, near32 PTR read2, 0

        mov     ecx,8                      ; loops through 8 characters
        mov     ebx,0
mov2:   mov     al,input2[ebx]
        mov     MsgBoxText[ebx],al
        inc     ebx
        loop    mov2

        invoke  MessageBoxA, 0 , ADDR MsgBoxText, ADDR MsgBoxCaption, 0
        invoke  ExitProcess, 0

end _start
```

This code works for the most part. When assembled and linked, the console window that launched the application will wait for the first input from the user. A five character string will be accepted and successfully used in the caption of the message box.

However I cannot get the program to pause for a second input. After entering the first input the program just skips right to the message box, correctly displaying the caption entered, but for the center text only the last portion of 'input' is displayed. I know that likely there are several things wrong with what I have done here, but I do not know where to begin.

This is an assignment project for an independent study course that I am taking for this summer, and I have been using the few coding examples that I have been given to produce this code. I am not asking for anyone to do my work for me, I just need someone to clue me in on what I'm missing here, or to at least point me in the right direction. Let me know if you need anymore information regarding my problem, thanks!

Comment: You probably entered more than 5 characters (including the enter at the end of the line) which is left in the input buffer and is then read out by the second `ReadFile` call. Do you know C at least?

Comment: I know C, and I suspected that might be part of the problem. The issue is that I cannot use C for this project, and there doesn't seem to be a simple solution to truncating the newline off of the input.

Comment: `ReadFile` reads bytes from file, it doesn't parse the content in any way, it's up to you to deal with that part. Indeed there's no simple solution, it's sort of like C, but without the `<string.h>`, so you have just `char wannaBeString[100];` array and do all the parsing on the code side. Another problem in your code is `input byte ?`, that's like `char input[1];`, but you read many more bytes into that array, overwriting the following memory. So one thing to do is to create your own "ReadLine" which will read all the bytes from STD_IN until CR+LF is reached (throwing out bytes over maxN).